# Why do we subtract λ from the diagonal of matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Well the question states it all.
Why do we subtract λ from the diagonal of matrix A to calculate eigen values?

Comment: No, the question doesn't state it all. Subtracting from a diagonal shifts all eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$ by $\lambda$, but that's about it. You might want to talk about where you saw this being talked about.

Comment: *Definition:* Eigenvectors $v$ of operator $A$ that correspond to eigenvalue $\lambda$ are solutions of $$Av=\lambda v \Longleftrightarrow (A-\lambda I)v = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then the following condition is satisfied:

$$A\cdot v=\lambda v=\lambda Id\cdot v\rightarrow (A-\lambda Id)v=0$$

with $Id$ denoting the Identity matrix.

Comment: could you explain the `d` in the expression

Comment: @Saad Id denotes the identity matrix $I_n$. So the $d$ is the second letter of the word *identity*.

Comment: added explanation of notation

Answer (score 4):

The equation $A \mathbf{x}=\lambda \mathbf{x}$ is the equation used to find eigenvalues.
Here is an [image](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Eigenvalue_equation.svg) describing what eigenvalues and eigenvectors do

By rearranging $A \mathbf{x}=\lambda \mathbf{x}$, we obtain
$$(A-\lambda I)\mathbf{x}=0$$
We multiply $\lambda$ by the [identity matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) $I$ since we are manipulating matrices.

Now, we realise that the only way that the only way that the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is nonzero is if the determinant is equal to zero.

Hence, we must evaluate:
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=0$$
Since the identity matrix $I$ only has $1$'s on its diagonal and $0$'s elsewhere, this is why $\lambda$ is subtracted on the diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$  be the endomorphism over a vector space $V$ represented by your matrix, the you have that

$v \in V$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda \Longleftrightarrow Mv=\lambda v$.

By linearity you obtain that  $Mv=\lambda v \Longleftrightarrow$ $(M-\lambda Id) v = 0$, where $Id$ is the identity matrix.

So to study eigenvalues and eigenvectors you reduce to study the Kernel of the endomorphism $M-\lambda Id$, that is a "simpler" problem.